# .htaccess: prevent access to files and prevent directory browsing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to prevent all file access and directory browsing for a directory without putting a .htaccess file in said directory.

For example, let's say this is in my root web directory:

```
.htaccess
index.php
myframework/
```

What do I put in that .htaccess file so that whenever anyone browses a directory or file in `myframework/` they will get a 403 forbidden.

Right now all I am doing is `Options All -Indexes` but this only prevents directory browsing - if they know an exact file URL inside `myframework/` then they would still be able to browse to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Have this code in your DOCUMENT_ROOT .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myframework/ - [NC,F,L]
```

- NC - Ignore Case comparison
- F  - Mark current URI Forbidden
- L  - Mark this rule as last

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite with

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Append this to your .htaccess;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^myframework/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```