# Allow only direct access on a specific folder name via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to allow direct access on a specific folder name (and subcontents) via .htaccess, and deny all other.

To start, my current `.htaccess` is:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

My file structure is, for instance:

```
    modules/
        core/
            _test/
            publics/
                file.txt
        other/
            _whatever/
                publics/
                    more.txt
            publics/
                sub/
                    file.txt
                other.txt
    .htaccess
```

I could not access anything, except by files and folders that are in `publics` folder. On this example, I could access, without problem:

- modules/core/publics/ [dir]
- modules/core/publics/file.txt
- modules/other/_whatever/publics/ [dir]
- modules/other/_whatever/publics/more.txt
- modules/other/publics/ [dir]
- modules/other/publics/sub/ [dir]
- modules/other/publics/sub/file.txt
- modules/other/publics/other.txt

I could not have access to any file or folder.

I guess that we will need regular expression, but I don't know how I can use this on mod_rewrite to works like I want.

Some suggestion?

Comment: Answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379355/htaccess-prevent-access-to-files-and-prevent-directory-browsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight modification to your current htaccess. Any access not under a publics folder will be redirected to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !publics/
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```