# .htaccess block access to files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using an `.htaccess` file, how can I block access to a folder and all of it's files? I know I can do `Options -Indexes` but that still allows someone to access the files in the directory and download them. I would like to also disable access to the files as well. Basically I want to make a storage spot in the website to store the PDF files used to create the images or anything else that I don't want the outside world to access.

Comment: Look at this SO for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610524/htaccess-to-restrict-access-to-folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379355/htaccess-prevent-access-to-files-and-prevent-directory-browsing Possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**Deny**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) to disallow access to your folder however putting those files in a place which is not publicly accessible (like outside of your web site's `DocumentRoot` folder) would be an even better solution.

Comment: I like this solution, I guess I will do that.